# How to retrieve a "gtag" (Google Tag) from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

I am developing a chrome extension that extends the functionality of our company portal. Our company does not own this portal; The portal is maintained and owned by a different company. If we want to change things, we cannot; We must ask said company to implement the change, and its up to them whether they do or not. So like I was saying, the extension does things to improve accessibility and navigation, as well as inserting specific bits of functionality that make it easier to use the website.

I want to make the extension specific to the user type, just like within the portal itself. Within our company portal, we have different roles: agents, admin, brokers, etc. However, there is really only one way for me to detect the type of user: gtag, or a google tag. The portal uses google tags, and I noticed while searching through their html, that there is a google tag for the user type. So my extension could in theory search the html to find the google tag, and extract the value for 'user-type'!

There is a lot of documentation on how to add a google tag to a website, but none to retrieve a google tag. However, I know it is possible. There is an chrome extension (provided by google) called [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) that does just this. It detects google tags on any page you are on, and then displays them in the extension's pop-out window.

How can I retrieve the `'user-type'` value from a google tag on a page?

Here is the code on the page I am looking at:

```html
<script>
gtag('event', 'page_view', {'user-type': 'admin'});
</script>
```

For this example, I need to extract the `'user-type'` value of `'admin'`.

I cannot think of anything very ingenious. So far, all I can think of is using jquery and regex patterns to get it. For example, this code accomplishes the task:

```js
$("script:contains('user-type')").text().match(/(?<=('user-type':\s\'))[a-zA-Z]+(?=('))/g)
```

I guess the I have an answer, but it just is not as elegant as I am thinking it should be.

How you would do it? Or am I overthinking this, and should stick with my current solution?

Comment: If you can insert or run your script before the gtag script, then you can do `const oldGtag = window.gtag; window.gtag = function(e,p,o) { if (o["user-type"]) process(o["user-type"]); }; oldGtag(e,p,o);`

Comment: Your solution is correct if the tag is present only as a text inside `<script>` element. You can also check a global `window.dataLayer` but you should do it in [page context](/a/9517879). The trick above with overriding `gtag` should also be used in [page context](/a/9517879).